# How do I get the last three vectors to complete this cube?

Tags: programming

Looking at this file, what vectors do I need to add to the cube:={...} in order to get a full cube?[image]

Comment: Please, post code as code, not as pictures...

Comment: Hint: `Graphics3D[{FaceForm[None], Cuboid[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}]}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> True]`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way that comes to my mind is to substitute your list of vertices for the list of vertices used to draw the cube available through `PolyhedronData`. The code for doing that would be

```
Module[{
    cube = {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, 
            {1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}},
    p = PolyhedronData["Cube", "Faces"]},
  p[[1]] = cube;
  Graphics3D[{FaceForm[None], p}, Boxed -> False]]
```

The result is a wire-frame cube with the vertices you specified.

[image: cube]